# LSTM Prediction Straight Line

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, prediction, yfinance

in my project I am tasked with predicting the exchange rate. To begin with, I decided to try to match the values ​​predicted by the LSTM model and compare them with the actual values. I display both types of values ​​on the graph, the problem occurs when I am executing model.fit(). The model tries to fit the predicted values, but instead of fitting a line graph of the values, it is a horizontal line. All predicted values ​​are the same regardless of the date. What can cause this problem? I tried different configurations of neural networks, optimizers, learning rate, activation functions, but nothing brings the expected results.

Data download

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = yf.download(
        tickers='EURUSD=X',
        group_by='ticker',
        threads=True,
        period='1mo',
        interval='1d',
        start='2021-01-01',
        end='2023-01-01'
    )

data['Date'] = data.index
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data["Date"] = pd.to_numeric(data["Date"])
prediction_table = pd.DataFrame(data[['Date', 'Adj Close']], index=None)



#Date
X = prediction_table.drop(columns='Adj Close')

#Adj Close
y = prediction_table.drop(columns='Date')

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

y[['Adj Close']] = scaler.fit_transform(y[['Adj Close']])

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
```

LSTM Model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(15, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Plotting

```
%%capture
plt.ioff()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches((16,10))
ax.plot(X.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1))
ax.set(xlabel='Date', ylabel='Adj Close', title='Currency rate exchange')
ax.grid(axis='both', visible=True, color='k', linestyle = '--')

plt.ion()
hfig = display(fig, display_id=True)
```

Actual Values:

[image: Actual Values]

model.fit()

```
plt.ioff()
for i in range(10000):
  model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1)
  y_pred = model.predict(X)
  lines = ax.plot(X.reshape(-1, 1), y_pred.reshape(-1, 1), color='red')
  hfig.update(fig)
  time.sleep(0.01)

  lines.pop(0).remove()
```

Red line - Predicted, Blue line - Actual

[image: Red line - Predicted, Blue line - Actual]

I tried different configurations of neural networks, optimizers, learning rate, activation functions, but nothing brings the expected results.

Comment: The model is linear because it has no activation functions, particularly in the hidden layer.

Comment: I already tried setting activation function to relu, but it doesn't have any effects. I have tried it before and now for ensure, but nothing changes.

Comment: You also trained for one epoch, which makes no sense.

Comment: I read that training for one epoch in loop should works. Maybe I didn't understand something.

Comment: That is not how your train a neural network, you train for enough epochs to reach convrgence, and then you look at the predictions, not before.